# Data in the list disappears on app restart?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here's the code
this is the list

```
List<String> favourites = [];
```

Here's the code that add items to list

```
Padding(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
 child: Container(
 color: Colors.black87,
  height: 400.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: favourites.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          color: Colors.black87,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              favourites[index],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ),
```

so when i restart the app the previous content of list disappears,so please tell me how to keep the saved items in a list permenantly.

Comment: Save your list in `SharedPreferences` using its `setList` method

Comment: i am new to flutter please share the code to do it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm giving you very basic idea, how to do that

```
SharedPreferences _prefs;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => setState(() => _prefs = prefs));
}

_saveList(List list) {
  _prefs.setStringList('key', list);
}

List _fetchList() {
  return _prefs.getStringList('key');
}
```

Comment: how do i save my list to it

Comment: Just call `_saveList` method and pass your list to it.

Comment: how to intialize this _savelist in listview builder

Comment: May I ask you how much experience you have in programming?

Comment: i am totally beginner

Comment: Please don't jump into Flutter or any other framework straight, spend some time in learning basic things about programming, pick any language and get your hands on it first otherwise you'll have very tough time.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion i will follow that

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your list in SharedPreferences. I recommend you use the shared_preferences plugin that you can find here: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences.

get your instance of SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

set list

```
prefs.setStringList('key', list);
```

get list

```
prefs.getStringList('key');
```

With your list saved in SharedPreferences, you can consider getting your data every time you open the app.

```
void main() {
  startUp();
}

Future startUp() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(MyApp(prefs));
}
```

Comment: how can i load my list as shared preferences

Comment: And how to access shared preferences with list view builder

Comment: To get your shared preferences object, you must call SharedPreferences.getInstance() at some point. On app bootup, or on your initState(), or whenever you want. Then, you should reference that SharedPreferences object (or its gettter/setter methods if you made it private). The plugin page that I linked has references, as well as the API: https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences-class.html

Comment: I don't see how is your code different than mine except you used it in `main`

Comment: Yeah it's quite similar - sorry, there was no answer when I started typing.

Comment: I answered 8 mins before you, not sure why didn't you see it.